# EXCEL - IF statement, with words

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum

Good afternoon,

I am looking for an Excel/GOOGLE Sheet =SUM(IF()) statement formula that will help to know if I have made or lost money in any given month. To save time when inputting the information, I would like to have once cell in the TOTAL row calculate what is a positive and negative number depending on the PAYMENT TYPE used, and printout the remainder.

This is also maintain inventory for when new items are added to my life during this one month period, because I'm just weird like that.

(See Google Sheet Link for example) [ie Expense Report](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_HN3Zh-CoS6DDVn1Xmj2DEqx5sq7HwC9iMzc4DXJS1E/edit?usp=sharing)

ie. My expenses are arranged by in a column PAYMENT TYPE: CC (for credit card, negative), CASH (negative), GC (for gift card, not added), or DEPOSIT (for income, positive).

The "added negative/positive" is how the balances should look: red for money spent (CC, CASH), gray for no expense (GC), green for money earned (DEPOSIT).

The =sum(if()) formula would then be able to easily calculate the end result, either in red (money lost) or green (money earned).

If there is another formula outside of =sum(IF()) that would do this job, I am very interested in seeing how it would be applied, so I can learn it.

Thank you for your responses, in advance.

-ECP03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, my current network blocks Google Docs so I can't view your example doc. From what I've gathered, you have a a couple information columns (expense, amount, etc) and then one column that includes the payment type. Here are 2 ways you could do this:

Assumption: you have **NAME** (Range A1:A5), **EXPENSE** (Range B1:B5), and **PAYMENT_TYPE** (Range C1:C5) as your 3 columns with 4 total transactions. Header is the first row (A1:C1). This assumes you will never have more than 1000 transactions to keep track of; just modify 1000 to whatever new max you require.

**1) This solution gives you your sum. It does not tell you the positive and negative contributions of the positives and negatives. For that see Solution 2.**

Set the cell that you want your net income to be to:

```
=SUMIF(C1:C1000,"DEPOSIT",B1:B1000)-SUMIF(C1:C1000,"CC",B1:B1000)-SUMIF(C1:C1000,"CASH",B1:B1000)
```

**2) This is the solution that shows both positive and negative contributions.**

Set aside 3 cells (say E1, E2, and E3). Set E1 to:

```
=SUMIF(C1:C1000,"CC",B1:B1000)+SUMIF(C1:C1000,"CASH",B1:B1000)
```

This is your 'negatives' cell. Set E2 to:

```
=SUMIF(C1:C1000,"DEPOSIT",B1:B1000)
```

Set E3 to:

```
=E2-E1
```

Then all you have to do is use conditional formatting (if you don't know how to do this just let me know or Google it) to set cell E3 to be green if the amount in it is > 0, red if it is < 0, and gray if it is = 0.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Judu Le.

That formula does the trick.

I did use your first answer.

ie. =SUMIF(C1:C1000, "DEPOSIT", B1:B1000) - (SUMIF(C1:C1000, "CC", B1:B1000)+SUMIF(C1:C1000,"CASH",B1:B1000))

The end result did not add or subtract the GC balance, which is what I wanted.

This worked perfectly. Thank you for your timely feedback.

-ECP03

Comment: Hi, if you found my post solved your problem, could you please mark it as the best answer? Thanks!

Comment: Also, just for clarification: how is your answer different from Solution 1 in my answer?

Comment: I meant to say I used your simplified version (1). Quick typing and movement. Apologies

Comment: No worries! Just glad I could help.